# Unable to set border-top for tab-content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I am unable to set `border-top` for `tab-content` class.

Although,I've declared `border-top`.It is not setting.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tab-content {
  border-top: 0.1em solid rgb(221, 219, 219);
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid rgb(221, 219, 219);
  border-right: 0.1em solid rgb(221, 219, 219);
  border-left: 0.1em solid rgb(221, 219, 219);
  width: 500px;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/70bzku90/3/)

Comment: `border-top` it set on `.tab-content`, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've set it.But it is not applying.If you observe,when the tab is active border-top of tab-content is not seen

Comment: Might it be [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/Ln903zn9/) you are trying to achieve?

Comment: that is okay.But, why it is not working using tab-content's border-top ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/Ln903zn9/) all you have to do is change `margin-bottom: -1px;` of your tabbable `li` tags.

They overlay your `.tab-content` and thus the top border is just now shown because the white background of the `li`s are above the border. Move them up for that spacing pixel and you can see the border.